# How can I find out which packages were not available?

Tags: package

When I run `package-install-selected-packages` I see the following message:

```
1 packages are not available (the rest already installed)
```

But it doesn't say which package was not available.

All the packages in `package-selected-packages` appear to have been installed, but apparently I requested something that was not available.

How can I find out what it was?

Comment: Manually?  I guess you can just look in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` and find out which of the packages you'd selected for installation is not present?  I would also review `*Messages*` with `C-h e`, as there may be an explicit indication logged in there.

Comment: Probably worth filing a feature request to Emacs maintainers to make this message say which packages weren't available.

Answer (score 5):

I just copied and modified the relevant snippet from `package-install-selected-packages`:

```lisp
(let* ((not-installed (seq-remove #'package-installed-p package-selected-packages))
       (unavailable (seq-filter (lambda (p) (not (assq p package-archive-contents)))
                                not-installed)))
   unavailable)
```

Pasted this into `*scratch*`, evaluated and got the missing packages.